# Unable to filter on a numeric field in a custom index

Tags: lucene.net, kentico

I have created a custom smart search index in Kentico but I am unable to get the index to return any results when I search against a four character year field.

I have tried adding the field to the index as an integer and used the suggested search syntax

```
publishedyear:10000002016
publishedyear:(int)2016
```

I have also added as a string and tried

```
publishedyear:2016
```

In all cases I am unable to get the search preview to return any results

Searching against an alphanumeric field such as

```
country:Canada
```

works fine.

I can view the index using the [Luke tool](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) and can confirm the expected values for publishedyear are in the index

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you've covered most bases. Have you tried changing the index analyzer type to Whitespace Analyzer? This has helped me target int fields in the past.

Comment: Thanks, Changing the analyzer type did the trick.